# How to combine multiple mp4 files into one using android's MediaMuxer api?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I want to combine multiple mp4 fiels into one video. There is an MediaMuxer class in Android framework and it seems that can do that. But I didn't find any clear sample for that. Is it possible to combine multiple video files(containing both video and audio) using MediaMuxer? If so, Could you please provide me a clear sample? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMuxer#History) MediaMuxer supports multiple video/audio tracks just for `mp4` format and only for `api +26` and not earlier versions. Also Some good samples can be found [here](https://www.mo4tech.com/mp4-example-analysis.html).